# Click link and Insert text from hidden field into input field, more than 1 time and replace the text in the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click link and Insert text from hidden field into input field, more than 1 time and replace the text in the input field.

Now my code only can insert text when the input field is empty, but I want it to replace the text if I click the "TestName" button

Anyone can help me? It doesn't matter if its javascript/Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">

function SetSearch(val, search) {
 $('input[id ^="SearchForm"]').each(function (index) {
  var s = "SearchForm" + search;
  if ($(this).attr("id") == s) {
    $(this).attr("value", val);
    return false;
  }
});
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:SetSearch ( $('#Name').attr('value'), 'Name' );">
TestName
</a>

<input id="Name" name="Name" type="hidden" value="TestName" />
Name
<input name="Name" type="text" id="SearchFormName" value=""  />
```

My fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fTpwF/2/

Comment: Are you sure that you've placed correct fiddle?

Comment: Use `$(this).val(val);`

Comment: Now its the correct fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.val(val)` instead of `.attr("value", val);`